# Infinite time LQR Problem

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control

Consider a linear system $\dot{x} = Ax + Bu$ with a quadratic performance index:
\begin{equation}
J = \frac{1}{2}\int_{t_0}^{\infty}[x(t)^TQx(t) + u(t)^TRu(t)]dt
\end{equation}

Now suppose any one of the states is unstable. Under this assumption, does this performance index make sense? Will J become infinite? All the solutions I see are working under the assumption that $x(t)$ is stable. But why can't we choose an $u$ to compensate unstable effect of $x(t)$?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA7Cj.png

Comment: What source are you using? And what do you exactly mean by that $x(t)$ is stable, that $A$ is Hurwitz? Normally for LQR it is assumed that $(A,B)$ is stabilizable.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Suppose I find $u = Kx$ and what I mean by stability is that in $\dot{x} = [A+BK]x$ [A+BK] is Hurwitz. The book I use is Optimal Control Systems written by naidu page 125.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen I put a picture of the statement which I look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your cited source states that the system (3.4.1)

$$
\dot{x}=A\,x+B\,u
$$

has to be *completely controllable*.

That would be a sufficient condition to ensure that an optimal solution has a finite value for the performance index, but it is not a necessary condition.

A necessary condition in order for the performance index to be finite using an the optimal solution and that the closed loop system is stable, is that $(A,B)$ is stabilizable and $(A,Q)$ is detectable, for example see [1]. The first requirement about stabilizability implies that all unstable modes of $A$ can be stabilized by $u(t)$ through $B$ and the second requirement about detectability implies that all unstable modes of $A$ contribute to a non-zero amount to the performance index through $Q$.

[1] Skogestad, Sigurd, and Ian Postlethwaite. Multivariable feedback control: analysis and design. john Wiley & sons, 2005.

Comment: Do you mean zero amount instead of non-zero amount?

Comment: @lordvoldemort no, namely if the contribution of an unstable mode to the performance index would be zero, then the optimal solution would be to not drive that mode to zero and thus the closed loop system would still be unstable. So if the contribution of all unstable modes is non-zero then the optimization problem has a "reason" to stabilize those modes.

Comment: Suppose by other means u is found to be $Kx$ where $K$ is a constant. Then $[A+BK]$ must be Hurwitz. Is this right?

Comment: @lordvoldemort if those previously mentioned requirements are satisfied and you want the performance index to be finite, then yes $A+BK$ must be Hurwitz.

Comment: Wouldn't that be $(A,C)$ detectable with $Q=C^TC$ instead of $(A,Q)$ detectable?

Comment: If the state has only one dimension, I think the system will be automatically controllable and detectable, meaning that only checking Hurwitz condition will be enough.

Comment: @lordvoldemort for a one dimensional state, so $A\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times 1}$ then one can still have that $(A,B)$ is not stabilizable if $A>0$ and $B=0$ and have that $(A,Q)$ is not detectable if $A>0$ and $Q=0$.

Comment: @KBS isn't detectability of $(A,C)$ with $Q=C^\top C$ equivalent to detectability of $(A,Q)$?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Yes, I have just checked and this is the case.